# Sign unsigned transaction with TrustWalletCore Swift

Tags: wallet, signature, ios, trust-wallet

I'm trying to understand how we can sign unsigned transaction in hex format.
We use TrustWalletCore, I receive an unsigned tx in hex format, then we decode it to data with

```
let dataToSign = Data(hex: unsignedTxHex)
```

then sign it with wallet core method:

```
`coinPrivateKey`.sign(digest: dataToSign, curve: .secp256k1)
```

and I tried:

```
`coinPrivateKey`.signAsDER(digest: dataToSign)
```

then covert it to `hex` again:

```
let signedStr = signedData?.toHexString()
```

And I tried to decode it using [this service](https://www.blockchain.com/ru/explorer/assets/btc/decode-transaction)

And receive error:
`"error": "Cannot read slice out of bounds"`

How I can resolve this problem? Thanks a lot for your comments and answers